# JSBuilder - trouble with command line build

Tags: terminal, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch application I am trying use JSBuilder to build which I am running this script in my Terminal:

```
bash  JSBuilder.sh -v -p airside.jsb3 -d .\AirSide
```

But I am receiving this error:
**JSBuilder.sh: line 11: ./jsdb/mac/jsdb: Permission denied**

I am not sure how to fix this or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `sudo` in front of the bash